# highcharts no point markers but show single point or discontinous points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've set markers in HighCharts to false for line charts, but I would this means that if the series a single point or if there is a discontinuous series like: [2.45, 7.89, null, 3.45] the 3.45 point would not show up at all on the chart. Is there a way to fix this?

```
        line: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
```

Comment: Yes - enable markers :)

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xL5zsunc ?

Answer (score 2):

The 3.45 point does appear on the chart - if you hover over where it supposed to be you can see it highlighted. Issue is there is no line connecting to it from your 7.89 because [`connectNulls`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cline%3E.connectNulls) is false by default. To see the points connected turn this to true. You can also enable a marker per point  not just per series:

```
series: [{
  data: [{
    y: 2.45
  }, {
    y: 7.89
  }, {
    y: null
  }, {
    y: 3.45,
    marker: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }]
```

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y0scy36/).

Comment: Thank you - the connectNulls is very misleading so I don't want to use that. I also didn't want a per point solution b/c I have series that have more than 1000 points sometimes from the server meaning I have to use array notation.

Comment: @user1387717 Your issue only occurs when you have one point between 2 `null` values. How often would that be the case? You could also try and set the marker to some other shape/size and enable it such that it does not go out of the line's width.